# Search for a pattern in a large number of file paths

Tags: algorithm, search, filepath

I have a data base with ~1.5G unique file paths collected from ~10K Windows machines. I need to lookup for patterns like

```
*win*.*
```

in the paths. Naturally paths are very similar one to another. Things like "c:\Users..." and "C:\Temp.." appear often. I can not ignore temporary files which constitute ~40% of all paths.

Average path length is 160bytes. The data base is large and does not fit the RAM.

Is there an approach which would improve the performance of a cloud based solution?

Thanks.

Update: wildcards can be different, but I could probably limit the possible wildcards to some preconfigured set. For example, only one or two stars.

Update 2: The wildcards patterns are similar with minor differences and often will contain only the basename or a part of the basename. Number of results is not going to be large. Usually I expect to get between 100s to 1000s hits. I do not need all results immediately in one large block, but if I get some results fast that would help and eventually I need to get to all results. The idea is to get the results inside 10s of seconds/couple of minutes.

Update 3.
Unicode strings support is required, but non English paths are relatively rare

Update 4. I understand that I can throw more machines and RAMs and get the problem solved. Unfortunately the constrain is to use a single machine (can be multicore with fair amount of RAM and SSDs) if possible.

Comment: What does 1.5G denote? Number of paths? Or combined size in bytes?

Comment: @StefanHaustein 1.5G is a number of unique paths.

Comment: Interesting idea is to use Windows indexer if enabled and produce a suffix tree. On the backend side I need to merge the suffix trees. Can I access the indexer data base?

Comment: @StefanHaustein The database contains all files ever created in the OS history and not only a snapshot of the filesystem. This is why the number of files is huge.

Comment: Because there is a significant overlap between filepaths I am thinking that I can compress the filepaths, sort the compressed filepaths, keep index of the longest overlap between a filepath and the previous filepath. Search in the first filepath lets me to search the non-overlapping part of the next filepath. I wonder if there is something ready which does the trick. I assume that the searched pattern is not less than 2 or three characters.

Comment: Probably there is a columnar database which can search strings fast? I mean really fast, like SSD read access speed fast.

Comment: You need to better define "search pattern".  Your current example appears to be the filename component only.

Comment: Could you clarify what "1.5G" means? Is that 1.5 billion? (I'm unfamiliar with the abbreviation.) Also, are the search patterns on the filename (last segment) alone or also on the rest of the path?

Comment: Anyone has experience with DataStax Enterprise Search?

Comment: @smarx 1.5G is 1000*1000*1000 entries

Comment: @Paparazzi Search pattern can be arbitrary, but base filename will be most  frequent

Comment: Arbitrary.  You expect help on how to design for an arbitrary search pattern.  Cloud based solution but you are limited machine.  This is just not adding up.   How are you pattern searching now?

Comment: @Paparazzi Please ignore the word "cloud". Currently this is a dedicated machine which runs the search. We index the folders part of the paths and the basename. We keep the data in a non-SQL database. The database supports search by wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try the following first (unless there are additional constraints making this impractical):

Split the paths at `\` and store the de-duplicated parts in a database table. If this set gets small enough to be searched within your time constraints, store the paths as lists of part ids, indexed by part ids, so you can find all the paths containing a given part by their id.

If a pattern crosses directory boundaries, you'll need to search for a partial pattern first, then filter the resulting candidates with the full pattern.

Comment: We have tried this approach. We tokenized the folders, compressed the tokens, indexed.  So far we have found that indexing the whole folder path and a basename makes the data base smaller. There are not many different folder structures, but lot of files. Still the performance just barely meets the constrains and there are lot of corner cases.

Comment: ... and we still need the solution to scale. Preferably to 20-30K Windows machine (~5B filepaths on a single server). Number of unique filenames grow almost linearly when we increase the number of PCs. Number of folder remains roughly the same.